# Does iOS have a unique device ID that I could use to salt a password hash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash, passwords, salt

I have a multi-user iOS application that needs to communicate with a mysql database. I'm using php to submit queries and return information in formatted in json. Will I need to hash the password in iOS as well as on the server side? Will sending it via https be enough security?

Comment: Your title and body don't match.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTTPS to send a password and hashing server side is enough. The only advantage of prehashing client side, is the reduced cpu power needed on server side.

The prehashed password actually becomes the new password, so if an attacker could eavesdrop the communication, he would see the prehashed password and could send it to the server as well.